# Please, how to count the number of element in a fields of a structure?

Tags: matlab, structure

I would like to count the number of element in a field of a structure in Matlab
The file name is "data.m"

I have something like this:[image: matlab struct]

- The file has 3 fields (Columns): x, y and z
- The file has maximal 6 lines, which is the number of line of the y-column
- x has 5 elements (0, 9, 5, 6, 6)
- y has 6 elements (6, 1, 2, 2, 8, 2)
- z has 4 elements (8, 8, 4, 9)

Using:

```
number_of_element = numel(data.x);
```

returns 1.
It only takes the first element (The first line, which is "0" here)
I would like to have the number of element of the column x, which is "5" in this case.

Then I tried this:

```
 number_of_element = numel(data(:,x));
```

But it doesn't work. I though Matlab could recognise "x" as a field name.

This also did not work:

```
 count = 0;
 for i = 1:end % I get an error because of this "end". Why is it not recognised here ?
    number_of_element = numel(data(i).x);
    count = count+number_of_element;    
 end
```

How could I get the number of element in the x-column ?
 Thank you in advance.

Comment: So you have an array of structs? Replace the `for i = 1:end` by `for i = 1:numel(data)` and the loop should work fine. `end` is not used while indexing, and thus Matlab does not know which variable to find the end of.

Comment: Thank you so much @rinkert. It does what I want.